# Generate all combinations of up to N digits, including repeating digits, in Perl

Tags: perl, combinations

What's the best way to generate all combinations of 1 to N digits, where digits could be repeated in the combination? E.g, given array 0..2, the result should be:

0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000
001
002
010
011
etc.

I've played with Algorithm::Permute, but it looks likt it could generate just unique combinations of N numbers:

```
for( my $a = 0; $a < 3; $a++ ) {
        for( my $b = 0; $b < 3; $b++ ) {
                my @array = $a..$b;
                Algorithm::Permute::permute {
                        my $Num = join("", @array);
                        print $Num;
                        sleep 1;
                } @array;
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name suggests,
[`Algorithm::Permute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute)
offers *permutations*. There are many mathematical variations on selecting ***k*** items from a population of ***N***: with and without replacement, with and without repetition, ignoring order or not

It's hard to be certain, but you probably want
[`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics)

Here's some example code that reproduces at least the part of your expected data that you have shown. It's pretty much the same as **zdim's** solution but there may be something extra useful to you here

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Algorithm::Combinatorics 'variations_with_repetition';

my @data = 0 .. 2;

for my $k ( 1 .. @data ) {
    say @$_ for variations_with_repetition(\@data, $k);
}
```

#### output

```
0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000
001
002
010
011
012
020
021
022
100
101
102
110
111
112
120
121
122
200
201
202
210
211
212
220
221
222
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my @digits = 0..2;
my $len = 3;
my @combinations = map glob("{@{[join ',', @digits]}}" x $_), 1..$len;
```